# Counting uppercase letters in a list excluding the first capital in a word

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my function must take a list of strings and return the total number of capital letters that appear in positions other than the beginning of a word. Also to break this problem into a sub problem, it needs a second function that takes a single word and returns the number of capital letters that appear in positions other than the beginning of that word. So far I have a function that works, but I have been told it needs to be done better and I am not quite sure how to do that.

```
def count_strange_caps(words):
    if words[0].isupper():
        count = abs(1 -sum(1 for c in words if c.isupper())
    elif words[0].islower():
        count = abs(sum(1 for c in words if c.isupper()))
    return count

def total_strange_caps(words):
    total_count = 0
    for word in words:
        if word[0].isupper():
            total_count -= 1
        for letter in word:
            if letter.isupper():
                total_count += 1            
    return total_count
```

My teacher told me to combine the two list comprehensions in count_strange_caps as they are basically the same code and use the code from count_strange_caps in the inner for loop for the second function.

```
print(total_strange_caps(["Five","FiVe","fIVE"]))
print(total_strange_caps(["fIVE"]))
print(count_strange_caps("fIVE"))
```

These are the types of tests it needs to pass and if anyone could help me with a solution using more rudimentary concepts it would be much appreciated. I can not use numpy if that makes a difference.

Comment: `sum(c.isupper() for c in words[1:])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `str.isupper()` and `sum()` to achieve this. Using these, the function definition of `count_strange_caps()` should be like:

```
def count_strange_caps(word):
     return sum(my_char.isupper() for my_char in word[1:]) # word[1:] to skip the first character
```

Sample run:

```
>>> count_strange_caps('HeLlo')
1
>>> count_strange_caps('HeLLo')
2
>>> count_strange_caps('heLLo')
2
```

Also, your `total_strange_caps()` can be simplified using `sum()` as:

```
def total_strange_caps(words):
    return sum(count_strange_caps(word) for word in words)
```

Sampl run:

```
>>> total_strange_caps(['HeLlo', 'HeLLo', 'heLLo'])
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string comprehension as follows:

```
def total_strange_caps(words):
    total_count = 0
    for letter in words[1:]:
        if letter.isupper():
            total_count += 1           
    return total_count

print total_strange_caps("AbCdE")
```

Output:
    2